# Null date in OData model does not work in DatePicker

Tags: datepicker, odata, sapui5, formatter

In my process we have a deadline which is a date. But this date is not set until a certain state has been reached. Say i want to display this date before it has been set and it is still initial.

The date is returned as a string and thus 00000000 in my model. (I understand that strings are not dates, but this was choosen and i have to go with it.)

Here is the control:

```
<DatePicker type="Date" placeholder="{i18n>DateStateUnknown}"
     enabled="{
        parts : [ 
            {path : 'settings>/incidentLock/MayChangeResponsible'},
            {path : 'DeadlineDate'} 
        ], formatter: 'com.company.inc.util.Formatter.mayChangeDeadline' }"
    displayFormat="long"
    value="{path:'DeadlineDate', 
            type: 'sap.ui.model.type.String', 
            constraints: { minLength : 2}, 
            formatter: 'com.company.inc.util.Formatter.setBaseDate'}"
    valueFormat="yyyyMMdd" />
```

My formatter looks like this:

```
setBaseDate: function(val){
   try{
    if(val=="00000000"){
                    return "";
                }else{
                    return val;
                }
            }catch(e){
                return "";
            }
        },
```

The diplay works as a expected. Nothing is displayed when the date is empty. The only thing is that with this formatter I loose my connection to the odata model. This means that whenever I make a change to the value, it does not reflect in the odata model and thus I cannot save this date. The same holds true when I set a value for the first time, when the control is still empty.

Does anybody know how to fix this? I'd rather not look at other options as hiding the field.

Comment: might the comparison val=="00000000" be wrong? Is it really a string containing 0000000 or might it be a number? find it out via console.log("correct") before returning the value ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to solve your issue is to

1. get rid of the formatter, and
2. have an empty date be `null` or an empty string, but anything other than `"00000000"`

Reason being, using a formatter makes your control readonly, [according to the API](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/a2fe8e763014477e87990ff50657a0d0.html):

> Currently, calculated fields work only from model to view, read only,
>   and the values can be accessed via a formatter function.

Furthermore, a date of "00000000" with format `yyyyMMdd` rightfully resolves to December 1, 1969, so if you want to avoid that, the date value should be something different than "00000000"

Comment: Thanks Robin, changing the date I think is not possible since SAP sees it as a date I cannot empty the value.

Comment: One possibility that might work -- depending on how your project is set up -- is to copy your OData model response to a local JSONModel. In your JSONModel, you can then freely manipulate the data as you wish, and upon submit, post the changed JSON data back to your ODataModel